# How do I hide a div when last task in an array is deleted?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a section on the edit page that gets filled with a message or a selection box depending on if the user has tasks to edit or not:

```
<div class="containerwrapper">
        <h3 id="crvenah3">Izmena zadatka</h3>
        <div class="containerwrappersub" id="containerwrappersub">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container_izmena" id="formaizmena">
            <div id = "levo">
            </div>

            <div id = "desno">
            
            <div id="skriveno" name="skriveno" class="skriveno">
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="text" value="" id="provera" name="provera" hidden="hidden">
            <input type="text" value="" id="obrisi" name="obrisi" hidden="hidden">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script>  
    function popuniOpcije() {
        let korisnik = "<?php echo $korisnik; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: '../funkcije/popuniOpcije.php',
            data: {
                korisnik: korisnik
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#levo").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    popuniOpcije();
```

This is the `popuniOpcije.php` file:

```
<div id="popuniovde">
</div>

<div class="prikaziizmeni" id="prikaziizmeni">      
    <h4 id="prikaziizmenitekst">The task has been updated<h4>   
</div> 

<script>  
    function popuniZadatke() {
        let korisnik = "<?php echo $korisnik; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: '../funkcije/popuniZadatke.php',
            data: {
                korisnik: korisnik
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#popuniovde").html(data);
                izaberi();
            }
        });
    }
    popuniZadatke();
```

This is the `popuniZadatke.php` file:

```
$zadaci = Zadatak::vratiZadatkeZaOpcije($korisnik, $konekcija);
?>

<?php if ($zadaci == null || empty($zadaci)) { ?>
<h4>No tasks to be edited</h4>
<?php } else { ?>

<h4>Zadatak</h4>    
<select id="zadatak" name="zadatak" onchange="prikazi(this.value); popuniDetalje(); sakrij();"required>

<option value="" disabled selected hidden><?= "Zadaci" ?> </option>
<?php

foreach ($zadaci as $zad) {
    ?>
    <option id="zadatakid" value="<?= $zad->zadatakID ?>"><?= $zad->naziv ?> </option>
    <?php
} }
?>
</select>
```

Whenever I delete a task from the page, the proper message gets displayed and the proper function gets called to either refresh the selection box or display the message that there are no tasks to be edited:

```
<div id="buttonwrapperizmena">
            <div class="buttoncontainerizmena">
                <button type="submit" class="buttonizmena" name="button" onclick="izmeniZadatak();"><span class="puntekst">Izmeni zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Izmeni</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="buttoncontainerizmena">
                <button type="submit" class="button2izmena" name="button2" onclick="obrisiSliku(); obrisiZadatak();"><span class="puntekst">Obriši zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Obriši</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

function obrisiZadatak() {
        let brojac = $(".zadatakid").length - 1;
        console.log(brojac);

        $("#formaizmena").ajaxForm({
            "beforeSubmit": function() {
            $("#prikaziizmeni").css("display", "flex");
            if (brojac == 0) {
                $("#prikaziizmeni").hide();
            } else {
                $("#prikaziizmenitekst").text("The task has been deleted");
                $("#prikaziizmeni").show();
            }
            $("#skriveno").css("display", "none");
            },
            "success": function() {
            popuniZadatke();
            }
        })
    }
```

How do I hide the `prikaziizmeni` div when the last task is deleted so that only the proper message gets displayed without the message of the task being deleted. I've marked the messages in English in the code since the functions' names aren't, it will be easier to spot

When I `console.log(brojac)` as `brojac = $(".zadatakid").length;`, I get 2 if there's 1 task left after pressing the button, i.e. deleting a task, so I added `brojac = $(".zadatakid").length;`.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

thats happen because $("#prikaziizmeni").hide() only hiding element but not removing from DOM. You must use .remove() method to fully remove element. After that lenght of list will be changed. If you have some transition you must use settimeout function or something like this:
`$('#prikaziizmeni').hide( 2000, function() { $( this ).remove(); });`

Comment: This doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: whats do izaberi();

Comment: and i don see in yor code when you trying delete task, just hide one element prikaziizmeni

Comment: you must also remove zadatakid. Something like this $('.zadatakid')[$('.zadatakid').last].remove()

Comment: right code `$('.zadatakid')[$('.zadatakid').length - 1].remove()` in the obrisiZadatak() - else